# HTML::FormHandler sort_column for HTML::FormHandler::Field::Select

Tags: perl, html-formhandler

The documentation for [HTML::FormHandler::Select](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::FormHandler::Field::Select) says that the [sort_column](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::FormHandler::Field::Select#sort_column) option `Sets or returns the column or arrayref of columns used in the foreign class for sorting the options labels.` I've tried setting it, but it is not setting my options:

```
has_field 'my_field' => ( 
    type => 'Select',
    sort_column => 'label',
    required => 1,
);
```

I've also tried not setting `sort_column`, since the default is to sort by the label column and that's what I want, but it doesn't seem to work still. Does anyone know how to have [HTML::FormHandler](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::FormHandler) sort the values of my select field? Currently the values are being set with an options function:

```
sub options_my_field { 
    return [
        {
            value => 1,
            label => 'One',
        },
        {
            value => 2,
            label => 'Two',
        },
    ];
}
```